# Get value from HTML input form with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am wanting to literally take the HTML form input with the ID "bet" and after the value has been entered and submitted; get the exact input for example: '100' may be entered, as I am wanting to perform an if statement to check that the value submitted isn't less than 0 for obvious reasons so then I can stop the webpage proceeding to perform the bet, and make the user instead enter a valid amount.

The code that I am having an issue with is below, upon loading the page I am getting the error: Notice: Undefined index: bet

```
<form action="duel.php" name="duel" id="duel">
<input type="text" id="betamount" name="betamount">
<?php
$data = $_GET['betamount'];
echo $data;
?>
</form>
```

I am fairly new to programming in PHP, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For forms that submit using `GET` as the method you can access the variables using the `$_GET` array - viz: `$_GET['id']` and for forms that use `POST` as the method you would use the `$_POST` array like `$_POST['id']`

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't a coding-site, we don't generate code for people in need. This is quite basic, Google around and you'll find a ton of guides. Try it our, and should you get stuck - come back here with a more specific question! You should look into `$_POST` and HTML forms. Also, PHP uses the name attribute, not the ID.

Comment: I have tried both $_GET['id'] and $_POST['id'] but I am getting an 'undefined index' error with the ID I am providing.

Comment: @Zunea As I said in my comment, PHP uses the name attribute from the input, not the id.

Comment: So where are you having trouble?

Comment: Both the name and the ID attributes are the same as 'bet', I have tried to change one of them then try again but to no avail.

Comment: If you show us what you have tried we might be able to help you. Otherwise we're just guessing...

Comment: I have just edited the post containing the code that I am having issues with. Sorry for not providing it sooner.

Comment: Hmm.. Are you trying to fetch the value of the input field without submitting the form (and reloading the page)? If that's the case, it can't be done with PHP... you need JavaScript for that.

Comment: I was trying to get the value after it has been submit, so if the bet amount was invalid for example: 0 then it wouldnt redirect to the final betting stage, and force the user to enter a valid amount. I have now got it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a name to the input element. In your situation, you could use the same name as your id:

```
<input id='bet' name='bet' type='text' value='100' />
```

To get the specific data for the 'bet' input field use:

```
echo $_POST['bet'];
```

On your server to view all of the post data use the code:

```
// Wrapping the output in the pre block makes the POST data easier to read
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example script you can use:

php file:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'];)) {
        session_start();
        $text = $_POST['Text'];
        echo "$text";}else {echo 'Could not load text!';}
?>
<form method="POST">
<input name="Text" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form
```

Comment: What does `session_start()` have to do with anything? And you should really explain what the script is doing and why it would solve the problem.

Comment: Hei du er Norsk. Because when you are using "POST" it loads a session in a method of "POSTING" a session, so if you do this without it may cause website to only display white, or it may output an errormessage.

Comment: Svensk. :) You are very wrong, my friend. Sessions and POST has nothing to do with each other... and I don't even know what "loads a session in a mehtod of "POSTING""-means... that sentence makes no sense.

Comment: Then i took wrong :) That happans, no one is mad because mistakes happens??

Answer (score -1):

So, you would make your form method "POST' and the action the url of the PHP script.

Then, in the PHP script you would use $_POST variable which would contain all of the info that was submitted in that form. See here:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

There is a similar variable for get requests. For hte difference in get and post methods see here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp